# Setting a default field value within a lightning quick action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-quickaction

Currently the following quick action is used to default to a particular record type when entering new records on the system.

I would like to set the "Name" field so that the value defaults to the following string based on the originating account: "Client Meeting: {!v.acct.Name}"

How do I do this?

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader"
            controller="AccountQuickEventWithRegCtrl">

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="fields" type="String[]" default="['Name', 'Contact_Name__c', 'Rheolwr_Cleient_Client_Manager__c', 'Project__c', 'Date__c', 'Discussion__c', 'Location__c', 'Update__c', 'Issues_Discussed__c', 'Meeting_Hours__c', 'Twristiaeth__c']"/>
    <aura:attribute name="acct" type="Account" default="{'sobjectType': 
                    'Account'}" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordLoadError" type="String" />
    <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader" recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  fields="Name"
                  targetFields="{!v.acct}" targetError="{!v.recordLoadError}" />

    <header class="slds-modal__header" style="width:100%; height:100%">
        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">New meeting with {!v.acct.Name}</h2>
    </header>
    <br/>
    <div  style="width:100%; height:100%">
        <lightning:recordForm aura:id="newEvent" fields="{!v.fields}" recordTypeId="0120O000000pF8wQAE" 
                          mode="edit" objectApiName="Event__c" 
                          onsubmit="{!c.submit}" onsuccess="{!c.saved}" oncancel="{!c.cancel}">
        </lightning:recordForm>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `force:recordData` events (recordUpdated).

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation) -

> The event fired when the record is loaded, updated, or deleted.

And in event handler, you can check if `changeType = LOADED`, then you can set Name field in that block.